# latex beamer toc - don't display bubbles

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I'm currently creating my first presentation using LaTeX's [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package.

Is there any way to change the enumeration symbol on the table of contents page?

Currently it looks like this, which is a little bit too "splashy?!" for me:

[image: LaTeX beamer table of contents]

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 32):

By setting the `section in toc`, `subsection in toc` (and possibly `section in toc shaded`, `subsection in toc shaded`) templates, you can change the formatting for the sectional unit entries in the ToC; here's a little example showing some alternatives for the section entries (suppressing numbering and balls, using circles, using unnumbered balls, and using squares):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsection}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[circle]
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\frame{test}
\section{Test Section Two}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, you can define your own style; for example, to suppress the ball and keep the numbers you could say:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\frame{test}
\section{Test Section Two}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a more elaborate example changing the way section and subsection entries are showin in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{%
  {\color{orange!70!black}\inserttocsectionnumber.}~\inserttocsection}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{bg=white,fg=structure}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{%
  \hspace{1.2em}{\color{orange}\rule[0.3ex]{3pt}{3pt}}~\inserttocsubsection\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\frame{test}
\section{Test Section Two}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\frame{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]